# How to run junits in play after Starting play application

Tags: java, junit, playframework, playframework-2.0

I have a bunch of JUnit tests and wanted to execute them. The tests access my Play application  **host:port** to call the REST API.

I use the following command to run the tests:

```
./activator  -Dhttp.port=8090 -Dhttps.port=8091  test
```

I also tried this way:

```
D:\sigma-idp\auth>activator  -Dhttp.port=8090 -Dhttps.port=8091  
[info] Loading project definition from D:\sigma-idp\auth\project
[info] Set current project to auth (in build file:/D:/sigma-idp/auth/)
[auth] $ test
```

But the problem here is that the application is not started yet and JUnit test tries to connect to the Play app to access my rest API. I am not sure why test did not start the application.

How can I start my play app before the JUnit test are fired?

Now I can execute tests only when the app is started using Eclipse.

Please suggest!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the documentation: 
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/JavaFunctionalTest
You have to explicitly launch your own webserver instance for testing:

```
@Test
public void testInServer() {
running(testServer(3333), new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        assertThat(
            WS.url("http://localhost:3333").get().get(timeout).getStatus()
        ).isEqualTo(OK);
    }
});
```

}

You should consider to test the controller directly (as recommended in the documentation).

Comment: I am doing in java. From document it is not getting cleared how should i follow. Also my rest calls needs to access embedded DB and the DB is started only when play app is started. I am not sure how can i fake all this.

Comment: As i told i need to access my embedded DB and that boots up only when play app is started.I have all my sample test data loaded in embedded DB.

Can you also provide a bit detail code of above example, as i think i cannot use as it somethings need to be reconstructed around it, i am not sure what?

Comment: you can pass a second parameter of type `FakeApplication` to the `testServer`-function, which contain your data or configure your db and add the appropriate test data. Here is an example: https://gist.github.com/schaloner/8454626

Comment: Is there any way i can start my play application before i run the test.... it need more then DB access

Comment: Maybe, if you need your application running to do your tests you should do integration or functional tests instead of unit tests. You can use tools like Gatling (http://gatling.io/) or JMeter (http://jmeter.apache.org/). I recommend Gatling - it's easier.